# How to register custom Vue components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I promise I've read every related post I can find, but I'm getting any clear answers (as far as I can tell, but I'm new to Vue).

**Details:**

- I'm using Vue v2.5.15
- We are using webpack (I've read that this may affect how I have to use components)

I'm attempting to use [this range slider component](https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/#/). I've tried to follow the documentation, but I keep getting an error stating `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vue-slider> - did you register the component correctly?`. I've tried reading the documentation and probably 20 different posts, but I'm still not getting this. Here is basically what I have in my JS file:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="app">
  <vue-slider
        v-model="sliderRange"
        :min="minPriceBase"
        :max="maxPriceBase"
  ></vue-slider>
</div>
```

```
// Javascript
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component';
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css';

export default {
  components: {
    VueSlider
  }
}

Vue.component('VueSlider', VueSlider);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  components: {
    VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
  }
});
```

I've also read through the [Vue docs on components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong. How do I correctly register my component?

**Update:**

I've discovered that if I use:

```
components: {
  VueSlider
}
```

Instead of:

```
components: {
  VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
}
```

Then I stop getting error mentioned above. Instead I get an error stating `[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "min". Expected Number, got Boolean`. But think it's progress? Why would `window['vue-slider-component'] be necessary?

Comment: Based on the error you're passing in a boolean value to min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs, i think you tried to do all the different import variants at the same time

```js
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
    }
  })
```

seems to be the suggested way of accessing the component that was appended to the window if you do a direct import via the script by adding

```
<script src="./node_modules/vue-slider-component/dist/vue-slider-component.umd.min.js"></script>
```

(which you aren't doing)

Then there is two more ways, you can install the component globally by using

```js
// main.js
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'

Vue.component('VueSlider', VueSlider)
```

which would then make the vue-slider available to all the components in your application, so you don't have to import it multiple times. If you do this, you won't have to also define it locally. And finally the third option is to import it only locally:

```js
// App.vue
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'

export default {
  components: {
    VueSlider
  }
}
```

This would make the slider component only available to a single component. In your case, you can decide to either go for option 1:

```js
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
Vue.component('VueSlider', VueSlider);
```

or option 2:

```js
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'

export default {
  components: {
    VueSlider
  }
}
```

The error you are seeing now by the way, is that your `minPriceBase` that you're referencing is not a Number, you would have to set that data on the instance:

```js
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'
import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'

export default {
  components: {
    VueSlider
  },
  data () {
    return {
      minPriceBase: 0,
      maxPricebase: 10
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that in your code you pasted the export before your vue instance, you don't need to export anything there, you just need to define that component on the vue instance:

```js
import VueSlider from 'vue-slider-component'

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  components: {
    VueSlider
  }
});
```

you should be able to get rid of this in your example, it doesn't do anything:

```js
export default {
  components: {
    VueSlider
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, there was same problem and there was also 500 server side rendering error.

Anyway, I fixed and used that by using require.

```
if (process.browser) { // I am not sure if it is needed for you.
  const VueSlider = require('vue-slider-component');
  Vue.component('VueSlider', VueSlider);
  Vue.use(require('vue-slider-component/theme/default.css'));
}
...

<vue-slider ...>
...
</vue-slider>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Telarian I added these codes to App.js. And I didn't need to reference vueslider and I just used it like `<vue-slider>`.

Comment: @Telarian Sorry, not `App.js`. It's in `App.vue`. :)